# Serialization of Closure is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, closures

I'm trying to rewrite some code in Laravel in order to make it a job and for that I'm doing the following:

```
$subscriptions->each(function ($sub) use ($payload) {
            $channel = $this;

            // new code
            dispatch(new SendOnePushNotification($channel, $sub, $payload));

            // old code below
            /*$this->webPush->sendNotification(
                $sub->endpoint,
                $payload,
                $sub->public_key,
                $sub->auth_token
            );*/

        });
```

What's causing this is passing $this to the SendOnePushNotification constructor.

My guess is that I could rewrite this somehow but I'm unsure how to begin. Any advice?

Comment: $this probably isn't a closure, is payload?

Comment: payload is actually just an array with some data in it

Comment: Well, what is `$this` then?